# processing: convert int to byte

Tags: processing, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert an `int` into a `byte` in Processing 1.0.9.

This is the snippet of code that I have been working with:

```java
byte xByte = byte(mouseX);
byte yByte = byte(mouseY);  
byte setFirst = byte(128);
byte resetFirst = byte(127);

xByte = xByte | setFirst;
yByte = yByte >> 1;
port.write(xByte);
port.write(yByte);
```

According to the Processing API, this should work, but I keep getting an error at   `xByte = xByte | setFirst;` that says:

```java
cannot convert from int to byte
```

I have tried converting 128 and 127 to they respective hex values (0x80 and 0x7F), but that didn't work either. I have tried everything mentioned in the API as well as some other blogs, but I feel like I'm missing something very trivial.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Processing before, but it's possible the `|` operator returns an integer regardless of the arguments' types. Try changing the problematic line to

`xByte = byte(xByte | setFirst);`

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I would have thought that processing would return a byte for byte comparisons, though.